# Alpine Linux Docker SSHD Image Uses VOL-save?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

One of the Alpine images I'm looking at has the following line in it:

```
RUN \
  apk --no-cache add openssh && \
  VOL-save /etc/ssh && \
  echo "root:root" | chpasswd
```

What does `VOL-save` do?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google gave me this; https://github.com/ekapusta/docker-alpine-base#tools

> `VOL-save` will backup directory inside container.
>   `VOL-restore` will restore container from container (usually into VOLUME).